# Href attribute in JavaScript showing only hash

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I print out an object of the HTML `a` tag: I see

```
href: "http://www.example.com/page.html#abc.1.2"
hash: "#abc.1.2"
```

When I do

```
$(document.body).on('click',"a",function(event){ 
    console.log( $(this).attr("href") );
});
```

I only get `"#abc.1.2"`, which is the value of the hash, not the whole URL. Why is that, and how can I get the whole URL?

Comment: What is the exact HTML that you are using?

Comment: jsFiddle please. Cannot replicate.

Comment: The href attribute is whatever literally appears in `href="xxx"`. The `.href` property is the full URL after merging with the current URL.

Comment: Next time, please also post the markup, people had to guess what it looked like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are getting the value of the *attribute* and not the property.

Use `.prop` instead of `.attr`.

Comment: `.prop()` is the same as `DOMelement.href` while `.attr()` is `DOMelement.attributes.href`. This is a good answer.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you're doing but this returns the HREF along with the host name and protocol

```
<a href="#abc.1.2">Link</a>

$(document).on('click',"a",function(event){ 
    console.log( this.href );
    return false;
});
```

Comment: I think the OP's HTML looks like this: href='#abc.1.2.3"

Comment: Oh well, then `console.log( this.href );` will return the host name as well

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to wrap `this` with jQuery to return a common property. Use instead `this.href`.

```
$(document).on('click',"a",function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.href)
});
```

Comment: `this.href` is not an attribute. It's a property.